# I need help with isomorphic graphs but with many nodes and all the same degrees!

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I know that to prove isomorphism I have to find out which nodes from one graph correspond with nodes from the other, but I am having issues with graphs with a lot of nodes and all of them have neighbors with the same degree!

[image: two graphs picture]

Can anybody please help out?

Answer (score 4):

The graph on the left contains triangles; the one on the right doesn't.